# How to get an public address for Azure SDK Python, before VM creation

Tags: python, azure, sdk, azure-virtual-network

I'm aware that the public ip is only generated after you set the vm. But is there a way to force the public ip to be dinamically created BEFORE the vm creation.

Mainly, I need to use the ip to generate the machine's name.

Or, is there a way to update the machine's name, before creation? I can find any information on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add Andrés Nava - .NET's answer. You should create a static Public IP before you create VM. Please refer to this [SDK article](https://azure-sdk-for-python.readthedocs.io/en/v1.0.2/ref/azure.mgmt.network.networkresourceprovider.html).

```
Gets or sets PrivateIP allocation method (Static/Dynamic)
```

When you create a static Public IP, it is associated a Public IP address and the IP address does not change. But if you create a Dynamic Public IP, it is not associated a IP address when you create the resource and the IP address will change when you stop VM.

Answer (score 2):

You can create the public IP before you create the VM. Then when creating the VM, associate the public IP to the VM's NIC.

Comment: That's the thing. I'm creating the Public IP before the VM, but the IP is only generated after the VM....